# how to deploy streamlit with secrets.toml on heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, streamlit

Hi I have an application that I would like to deploy on heroku. The question is how would I deploy a streamlit app with secrets.toml?

Currently the connection can be done locally via this

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
    st.secrets["gcp_service_account"])
```

However when I deploy it to heroku, this doesn't seem to connect.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On heroku I entered the gcp_service_account credentials as a config var (from the heroku dashboard go to 'Settings' --> 'Reveal Config Vars' as below:
[image: heroku config vars]

Instead of `st.secrets["<key>"]`, use `os.environ["<key>"]` in your python code as below:

```
gsheet_url = os.environ['private_gsheets_url']
```

For nested secrets like the gcp service account credentials, I first parse the json string as below:

```
parsed_credentials = json.loads(os.environ["gcp_service_account"])
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(parsed_credentials,scopes=scopes)
```

Hope this helps.